# how to get current timestamp in a gremlin traversal?

Tags: gremlin

Is there a way to do something like that in Gremlin traversals?:

```
g.addV("User").property("createdDate",now())
```

this should create a Vertex of label User with a field `createdDate` containing current timestamp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

`g.addV("User").property("createdDate",System.currentTimeMillis())`

That worked for me on DSE Graph

Comment: thanks! I didn't know I had access to java system variables through Gremlin console

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
g.addV("User").property("createdDate", new Date())
```

This will work in gremlin console.